# Окончание загрузки

Tags: html, jquery, браузер

Мне необходимо, при загрузке страницы, чтобы пользователь прогрузил все JS файлы для корректной работы с сайтом.

Вопрос: 1) Как узнать, что страница закончила загрузку?

2) Как узнать, что файлы в кэше?

Comment: 1) Поскольку есть метка `jquery` - положите ваш код в функцию `$(function($) {})`  2) Зачем вам это?

Comment: @tutankhamun Метка jquery подрозумевает, что допускается вариант с использованием JQuery. Я ведь написал, что для корректной работы с сайтом.

Comment: "корректной работы с сайтом" - очень расплывчатая формулировка. Вы бы лучше написали какие именно проблемы у вас возникли из-за того, что вы не знаете файл в кеше или нет. На первый вопрос ответ у вас есть

Comment: @tutankhamun К примеру, не загрузил пользователь библиотеку JQuery и полетит всё, что работает при помощи JQuey меню, ajax и т.п. Речь идёт о мобильном трафике, скорость интернета у всех разная и не весь земной шар покрыт высокоскоростным интернетом.

Comment: Скрывайте весь контент в одном контейнере, поверх какой-нибудь прогресс-бар или надпись. После загрузки JQ скрываете прогресс-бар и показываете контент. Но на этом обычно никто не заморачивается

Comment: Ну это я знаю. Как мне понять, что пользователь загрузил библиотеку JQuery?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45243/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and--).

Answer (score 1):

(Ответ для случая обычных скриптов, не async и не defer; если вы не знаете что это, значит скрипты не async и не defer :)

В силу ряда причин (таких как `document.write`) браузеры вынуждены загружать и выполнять скрипты сразу же после того, как встретят их в html-коде. То есть для данного тега `<script>` гарантированно, что все предыдущие скрипты уже загружены и выполнены (возможно, с ошибками, то таки выполнены):

```
<!-- Перед этим тегом jQuery ещё нету -->
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Здесь jQuery уже абсолютно точно загружен, присутствует и работает -->
<script src="path/to/some_script_uses_jquery.js"></script>
```

Как следствие этого, браузеры приостанавливают вывод html, находящийся после скрипта, до тех пор, пока скрипт не загрузится и не выполнится. Именно поэтому все скрипты рекомендуют размещать в конце страницы прямо перед `</body>`: чтобы пользователь во время загрузки скриптов видел хоть какое-то содержимое страницы, а не белый экран.

После того, как браузер дойдёт до `</html>` и закончит парсинг страницы, отправляется событие `DOMContentLoaded`; в момент его вызова можно быть уверенным, что все скрипты (не async и не defer) уже загружены и выполнены, а весь html-код распарсен и доступен через DOM (однако картинки и другие файлы не обязательно доступны):

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log("3: " + (window.jQuery !== undefined));
    // true - на момент DOMContentLoaded jQuery уже загружен
  });
  
  console.log("1: " + (window.jQuery !== undefined));
  // false - на момент выполнения этого скрипта ещё не загружен
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  console.log("2: " + (window.jQuery !== undefined));
  // true - перед выполнением следующего скрипта
  // браузер выполняет предыдущие, и jQuery уже есть
</script>
```

Кроме `DOMContentLoaded` есть ещё событие `load`, которое появляется, когда загружена вся-вся страница целиком, включая картинки и прочие файлы. Но я привязываться к нему не рекомендую, потому что, во-первых, большие картинки на медленном интернете могут сильно задержать полную загрузку страницу, а во-вторых, пользователь может остановить загрузку страницы, и этого события вообще не будет. Обычно все скрипты привязывают к `DOMContentLoaded`; сам jQuery делает так же.